# how to stream a request response object to hdfs

Tags: python-3.x, webhdfs

I am downloading a huge request file object (a gz file) from an API call. However, I am not sure the best way to write this file directory to hdfs (not creating a local copy of the file). I tried with hdfs client package in python and was having trouble with "ssl: certificate_verify_failed" even I set verify=False with keberose client. Is there a good way to do this?

I tried with hdfs client package in python but I failed with "certificate_verify_failed: error